# How can I instruct a build to use their dependency version if they have one, else use the one in my artifact

Tags: maven

I am creating a Java library in Maven that has a dependency on a third party library.

In case any consumer applications already use that third party library, I want their build to use theirs. However in case they don't already have it, I want them to use the one I packaged in my archive.

Is there a Maven way to have your cake and eat it too, so that I can tell consumer applications to use theirs if they have one, else use mine?

Comment: Thing is, the library is not in any position of dictating how its consumers should behave. You're probably trying to solve a 'version mismatch' problem in the wrong way: it is up to the client of your library to make sure they use the correct things.

Comment: What would be the possible differences between your version of the library and the consumer version of the library? The customer might have newer version of the library? Or a different library with the same classes? Why do you want you replace your own version of the third party library (if this is the one you tested against)?

Comment: I want to avoid conflicts with arbitrary consumers. If they already have a version of the library, I don't want to force them to use my version. But if they don't, I must provide mine. The library in question is Bouncy Castle, but a more common case would be logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When multiple versions of an artifact are found maven will attempt to select the version. It uses the nearest definition from the dependency tree.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
http://techidiocy.com/maven-dependency-version-conflict-problem-and-resolution/

This means that if the project consuming your library specifies a different version that will be used. If the common dependency is specified by a transitive dependency the version closest to the root of the tree will be used.

You can also use version ranges to specify many versions that work for you library.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN402